# How can I modify my xml file in actionscript 3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, xmlhttprequest

I have xml file on internet like http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml.I can read this xml file in actionscript.but I want to modify this xml so I want to add xml node or delete xml node.

for example:

```
<note>
 <to>Tove</to>
 <from>Jani</from>
 <heading>Reminder</heading>
 <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I want to add into my xml note's node

```
<example>mynodecontent</example>
```

Later I want to modify, such as the following XML on my xml file

```
<note>
 <to>Tove</to>
 <from>Jani</from>
 <heading>Reminder</heading>
 <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
 <example>mynodecontent</example>
</note>
```

is it possible?

Comment: This link could be useful for you: http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withflashcs3/?page=4

Answer (score 0):

try to this:

```
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml"));
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

var newNode:XML = <example>mynodecontent</example>

function processXML(e:Event):void
{
    var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);

    myXML.insertChildAfter(myXML.body, newNode);

    trace(myXML);
}
```

**if you want to send modified XML you're link. must have a server PHP codes or others.**

Comment: I said on my question so my xml file on internet.  ror example : http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml . I want to modify this xml

Comment: Later I want to see that in my xml file on link. new xml have to be myXML+ newNode on my link

Comment: If you want modified later upload to link. must have a server PHP or other .

Comment: read a this article: http://madssj.com/blog/2008/07/30/actionscript-3-posting-xml-data-with-urlloader/